# Does Oracle Synonyms for table cause a race conditions?

Tags: oracle, insert, synonym

I have use a synonym for a table in a Remote database. Application in remote site will insert data to source table, and my application will read those data via the synonym of the table.

Remote site application will send a TCP message after inserting a record to source table. My application execute a fetch once received that message. 
But i detect that some records are fail to fetch because that does not available in the Table (Synonym) at the time of TCP message received.

Is there is possibility of having race condition in inserting and fetching in Synonyms ?

Comment: Is the source application `commit`ing before it sends out the message? Is the target application keeping an open cursor?

Comment: Yes, Source application commit the insert SQL before send TCP Message. Target application does not close DB Connection until Terminate the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The presence (or absence) of a synonym has no impact.

If the source application commits before sending the notification and if your application is using the default read committed transaction isolation level, your application will see all the rows that were committed when it queries the database.  The only exception that I am aware of would be if the remote database is a RAC database where the `MAX_COMMIT_PROPAGATION_DELAY` is set to a non-zero value.  Unless the remote database is an older (pre-10.2) version of Oracle, that would only be the case if someone had changed the default value for that parameter.

You can determine the Oracle version by looking at `v$version`

```
select * 
  from v$version
```

You can determine whether `MAX_COMMIT_PROPAGATION_DELAY` has been set by querying `v$parameter` (this will return 0 rows if the parameter has not been set)

```
select name, value 
  from v$parameter 
 where name = 'max_commit_propagation_delay'
```

You can determine whether the database is a multi-node RAC cluster by querying `gv$instance`.  If this returns a `count(*)` of greater than 1, it is a multi-node RAC database

```
select count(*) 
  from gv$instance
```

Comment: How can i check that in the DB ? Can i check that via SQLPLUS

Comment: @Janaka - Assuming you are connected via SQL*Plus to the remote database, `select * from v$version` will give you the version of Oracle, `select name, value from v$parameter where name = 'max_commit_propagation_delay'` will give you the max propagation delay (assuming it has been set), and `select count(*) from gv$instance` will tell you how many instances of the database there are-- if that is more than one, it is a RAC database with multiple nodes.

Comment: My DB version is "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production    
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production                                          
CORE 11.2.0.1.0 Production                                                      
TNS for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production                                
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production  " And max_commit_propagation_delay is not exist in this DB Version.

Comment: @Janaka - If the parameter is not set, it has the default value of 0.  So even if the database is a multi-node RAC cluster, a committed change on one node will be immediately visible to queries executed on other nodes.

Comment: Data inserted by a Procedure and it use autonomous transaction. Does that effect for this issue ?

Comment: @Janaka - Why are you using an autonomous transaction?  Is the procedure with the autonomous transaction writing the actual data that your application is querying?  Or is it writing to some sort of log table and your application is using that log data to query other tables where the actual data changes may not have been committed yet?